# Azure Device Update for IoT Hub & Deployment

Tags: cicd, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-update

We had a deployment issue yesterday regarding the Azure Device Update for IoT Hub component.

We regularly conduct deployments and have never encountered this issue before.
Yesterday, 2 out of 3 of our CI/CD pipelines failed due to a lack of permission: **Microsoft.DeviceUpdate/locations/operationStatuses/read**.

We searched for a Built-in role containing this permission but found nothing. In order to restart our pipelines, we created a custom role with only this permission and associated it with the identity linked to the pipelines.

Questions :

Has anyone else encountered this issue and could explain it to us?
Why is it appearing now and only on 2 out of 3 pipelines?
What is this permission related to?
What is the specific action that the pipeline is trying to resolve?